# Loop Through a Specific Set of Charts in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I want to loop though only a specific set of charts in one sheet and then apply to those a set of formating (title font size, title position, axis size, grid lines formating etc.)

The problem ist that there are already 66 charts on that sheet that were manually created (1 to 66). I will now add more charts but automatically generated, and only for those ones I would like to apply the formating needed.

For now I managed to create the charts and apply the formating separately. But in order to make it more fluid I would require a loop that I have not figured out yet. My idea was/is to count all Charts on the sheet and then do something like "If cnt > 66 Then "put here the code starting from the cht.Activate line".

My problem is counting all the charts. I am guessing using something like

`with For -> For i to .CharObjects(i)`. But maybe you can suggest a different way.

```
Public Sub TEST()

Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject, cht1 As ChartObject, cht2 As ChartObject, cht3 As ChartObject
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wsG As Worksheet:     Set wsG = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
Dim wsS As Worksheet:     Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")

LastRow = wsS.Cells(wsS.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = wsS.Range("A4:B" & LastRow)
Set rng2 = wsS.Range("H4:I" & LastRow)
Set rng3 = wsS.Range("O4:P" & LastRow)
Set cht1 = wsG.ChartObjects.Add(Range("A595").Left, Range("A595").Top, Width:=518.5, Height:=296.7)
Set cht2 = wsG.ChartObjects.Add(Range("M595").Left, Range("M595").Top, Width:=518.5, Height:=296.7)
Set cht3 = wsG.ChartObjects.Add(Range("Y595").Left, Range("Y595").Top, Width:=518.5, Height:=296.7)

cht1.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng1
cht1.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
cht1.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
cht1.Activate
    With ActiveChart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""NAME 1"""
    .ChartTitle.Text = "TITLE 1"
    End With

cht2.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng2
cht2.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
cht2.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
cht2.Activate
    With ActiveChart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""NAME 2"""
    .ChartTitle.Text = "TITLE 2"
    End With

cht3.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng3
cht3.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
cht3.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
cht3.Activate
    With ActiveChart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""NAME 3"""
    .ChartTitle.Text = "TITLE 3"
    End With

For Each cht In wsG.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate
    With ActiveChart
        .Legend.Delete
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
        .ChartTitle.Select
        With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.150000006
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        Selection.Left = 27.536
        Selection.Top = 5

        .ChartArea.Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoFalse
        End With

        With .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font
        .Size = 11
        End With
        .Axes(xlValue).Select
        Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .DashStyle = msoLineDash
        End With
    End With
Next cht

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not format the charts as you generate them?

Comment: True. Did not think of that. Thanks Chris, will give it a go now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore `Chart 3` and `Chart 2`, add these two names to an array. Then check whether the chart object has name from this array and act accordingly:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim chartCount As Long
    Dim cnt As Long

    Dim chartNamesToExclude As Variant
    chartNamesToExclude = Array("Chart 3", "Chart 2")        
    For Each myChart In Worksheets(1).ChartObjects
        If Not valueInArray(myChart.Name, chartNamesToExclude) Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            myChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Title" & cnt
        End If
    Next myChart

End Sub

Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim cnt As Long    
    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function
```

The code above loops through all the charts in `Worksheets(1)` and changes their titles accordingly to `Title N`. It ignores the charts with names `Chart 3` and `Chart 2`, by seeing that these are in `chartNamesToExclude` array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vityata. You solution worked but I think I have found what I was looking for in the beginning. I am not sure if it is better, but it does the job also. Here it is. Cheers, Daniel

```
Private Sub newtest()

Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject, cht1 As ChartObject, cht2 As ChartObject, cht3 As    ChartObject
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wsG As Worksheet:     Set wsG = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts Radio")
Dim wsS As Worksheet:     Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Raw")
Dim i As Long


For i = 67 To wsG.ChartObjects.count
    wsG.ChartObjects(i).Activate
        With ActiveChart
            .Legend.Delete
            .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
            .ChartTitle.Select
          With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.150000006
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
          End With
        Selection.Left = 27.536
        Selection.Top = 5
      'Added more formating / code here
    End With
Next
End Sub
```